# Will there ever come a point where you can take the gain margin using the phase at 0 degrees?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, stability

I understand that we use the magnitude at -180 degrees since when k increases, the nyquist plot expands and the frequency that will first touch the pole will be the frequency where the phase is -180 degrees. But seing as 0 degrees also makes the transfer function real without imaginary roots, will there ever come a point that we will use 0 degrees as a basis for phase in determining the frequency?

Comment: What's the point of doing this?

Comment: just curiousity and to gain a better understanding of the topic.

Comment: What topic would you be trying to get a better understanding of (it can't be gain margin because that's done at 180 degrees)?

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification:

- When the necessary phase inversion for negative feedback at the summing node (in some cases within the loop) is NOT taken into account, the gain margin definition needs the 180deg criterion.
- However, when the loop gain is defined for the complete loop (including ALL phase inversions for negative feedback) we must use the 0 deg criterion. This is the case for loop gain simulation when the loop is opened at a suitable point. In this case, the loop gain phase plot starts at very low frequencies (in particular, for DC) at -180 deg.